# Rails migration to reference a User, how to add this foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a 2 Models, User and Post.

I want the Post model to have a User in it i.e. add a user_id in the Posts table.

What will my migration look like?  Or do I just do this manually like:

```
add_column :posts, :user_id:integer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yep, just do it manually. It'll look like this:

```
class AddUserIDToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```